# Explanation on Enhanced MetaFile

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I have started learning about MFC recently and the first thing that is really confusing to me so far are Enhanced MetaFiles, specifically, the purpose of and the difference between the bounding rectangles in these two functions

```
BOOL CreateEnhanced( 
   CDC* pDCRef, 
   LPCTSTR lpszFileName, 
   LPCRECT lpBounds, 
   LPCTSTR lpszDescription  
);


BOOL PlayEnhMetaFile(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  HENHMETAFILE hemf,
  _In_  const RECT *lpRect
);
```

I've written a function `DrawLogo` that creates Enhanced MetaFile like this:

```
CMetaFileDC mf;
CString mf_name = CString("name.emf");
CRect bnds = CRect(0,0, 8000, 8000);
mf.CreateEnhanced(pDC, mf_name, &bnds, mf_name);
//some drawing...
mf.CloseEnhanced();
```

And then, I "play" it like this from another function:

```
CString mf_name = CString("name.emf");
DrawLogo(pDC);
HENHMETAFILE hmf;
hmf = GetEnhMetaFile(mf_name);
ENHMETAHEADER mfh;
GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hmf, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER), &mfh);
int width = mfh.rclBounds.right - mfh.rclBounds.left;
int height = mfh.rclBounds.bottom - mfh.rclBounds.top;

TRACE("WIDTH = %d", width);
TRACE("HEIGHT = %d", height);

PlayEnhMetaFile(pDC->m_hDC, hmf, CRect(0, 0, width, height));

//and I draw a rect using same bounds
CRect frame = CRect(0, 0, width, height);
pDC->Rectangle(&frame);
```

So my expectation was that metafile will be INSIDE of `frame` CRect, but that is not the case - the image exceeds the rect bounds.

Can anyone provide an explanation? Thank you.

EDIT:

As requested:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to get an idea of your output? You say the image bounds exceed the rectangle bounds? How large is the image comparing to the rectangle? BTW, why don't you use the `PlayMetaFile` member of `CDC` and instead use the Windows API `PlayEnhMetaFile`?

Comment: The rect passed to `CreateEnhMetaFile` is in .01mm units while the rect passed to `PlayEnhMetaFile` is in logical units i.e. pixels. Could that account for the difference? What do your `TRACE` statements display?

Comment: @MariusBancila I've added screenshot.

Comment: @MarkRansom TRACE output:
WIDTH = 228 HEIGHT = 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RECT` passed to `PlayEnhMetaFile` is only used to scale the image drawn based on the bounding box supplied when the metafile was created. If the metafile draws outside the bounding box then it will also draw outside of the `RECT`. If you want to the image to be clipped to `RECT` then set a clipping region on the DC before playing back the metafile. If you want to the image to be scaled so that it fits inside the `RECT` you'll need to provide the correct bounding box when you create the metafile.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be scaled. The thing is I don't really understand what is a purpose of `RECT` in `CreateEnhMetaFile`. Shouldn't it scale the whole image to that rect when saving it?

Comment: The bounding box you supply when creating the metafile doesn't affect the image at all when its saved. The metafile is not scaled or clipped to the bounding box. If you draw outside the bounding box, the metafile will draw outside the bounding box. If you don't want this, you need to calculate a bounding box that encompasses everything you draw.

Comment: Much clearer after your answer, docs on msdn didn't help me at all. Thanks, man.

Comment: I just noticed from rereading the documentation that if you pass a `NULL` pointer as the `lpRect` parameter to `CreateEnhMetaFile` it will calculate the bounding box for you.